# XUnit Test add Autofixture dont mocking DI

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, autofixture

I try to use AutoFixture in this test:

```
[Fact]
public void testLogin()
{
    var response = new Mock<IServiceSomething2>();
    response.Setup(r => r.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin());

    var sut = new Authenticate(null, response.Object, null, null, null);
    sut.LoginGo("", "fake");

    response.Verify(a => a.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin(), Times.Once());
}
```

With

```
Authenticate(IServiceSomething1 i1, IServiceSomething2 response, Func<Obj1> login, Func<Obj2> func2, Action<string> action)
{
    _i1 = i1;
    _response = response;
    _login = login;
    _func2 = func2;
    _action = action;
}
```

I try this:

```
[Fact]
public void testLogin()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var response = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IServiceSomething2>>();
    response.Setup(r => r.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin());

    //fixture.Register(() => response.Object);
    fixture.Inject(response.Object);

    var sut = fixture.Create<Authenticate>();
    sut.Login("", "fake");

    response.Verify(a => a.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin(), Times.Once());
}
```

and this:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() 
      : base(() => new Fixture().Customize(new  AutoMoqCustomization() {}))
    {

    }
}

[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void testLogin([Frozen]Mock<IServiceSomething2> response, Authenticate sut)
{
    response.Setup(r => r.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin());
    sut.Login("", "fake");
    response.Verify(a => a.RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin(), Times.Once());
}
```

But i can´t because the `RedirectToLoginPageWithInvalidLogin` method doesn´t mocking.

Can you help me?

Comment: When you say 'method doesnt mocking', is there an error that occurs when you execute this test? What is the error you are getting? Or is it that your expected test result does not appear?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this. The problem was that the interface was readonly and for don't change that i need to do this

var ex = fixture.Build().FromFactory(() => new Authenticate(null, response.Object, null, null, null)).Create();

I don't find other answer